# How to dismiss mac mail windows that seem to be lost

Tags: macos, mail.app

For several months now I have had two mail windows that appear in the popup menu
as shown in the image, but the windows are not selectable.  When I select them with
the mouse, nothing happens.
The windows have the title "Re: OFA EPITA_Dates des soutenances de fin d'apprentissage".

I've tried quitting the mail app and rebooting but they persist.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: I have had some success with this procedure: select the window from that menu and then immediately press COMMAND-W. Repeat for the second window. If they do not disappear from the menu then my technique failed, sorry...

Comment: Another thing to try: bring the Mail app to the foreground, then press Command-W until *all* Mail windows are closed, then choose File menu > New Viewer Window to reopen the normal window.

Comment: Do these ghost windows actually represent _existing_ email messages in your Inbox? That is, can you search using that very long unique string to find the message(s) themselves? ~ I haven't used Apple Mail lately but on my Mojave Mac, there is rebuild function found in the Mailbox menu > Rebuild. Have you tried that?